# Website logo appears bigger in chrome browser on bigger screen

Tags: html, css, image, web

I have website which has a logo in size 250X277. The logo is correctly displayed across all browsers except Chrome running in bigger wondow, e.g. dekstop. In desktop, the logo stretches horizontally as it's shown in the image below. However, in other browsers it's displayed correctly across all monitor size. I will provide more code if that requires. 
Could someone please have a look on my issue?

Here is my CSS code for logo:

style.css:

```
header {

  position: relative;

  z-index: 999;

}

header .header-logo {

  padding: 10px 10px;

  background: #fff;

  text-align: center;


}
```

HTML

```
            <header class="sidebar-section">
            <div class="header-logo">
                <a class="logo" href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" width="250"></a>
            </div>
            <a class="elemadded responsive-link" href="#">Menu</a>
            <div class="navbar-vertical">
                <ul class="main-menu">


                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*For me at least, the logo does not seem to stretch in neither Chrome nor FireFox.
Have you recently made changes to the dimensions of the logo, and viewed these changes in Chrome?
CSS will stick in chrome cache, so you should always do CTRL + F5 when watching newly changed CSS edits in browser.*

**Edited answer**

The issue relies with your bootstrap configuration.

You use Responsive Design, to make the site change depending on how big the monitor it's being viewed on is.

To fix this issue, open your **css/style.css** file, and inside the media-query "**@media (max-width: 1199px)**" add something like `.logo{width:219px}`

**Edited answer 2**

You can also just set the static size of the image to 210px.
This will look good in all 3 breakpoints.

```html
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" width="210px">
```

Comment: Actually, I retract this statement.

The issue seems to be with your breakpoints.
Are you perhaps zoomed in in the Chrome window?

The logo is broken on both Chrome and FireFox when exceeding the 1200px breakpoint.

Comment: Fox, thanks for reply. The logo's width gets bigger only on bigger screen, e.g., in desktop monitor. However, in smaller monitor it seems okay. You can see my attached pictures, the logo has widened from it's white box and became wider.

Comment: Yes, that's because you use bootstrap break-points to make your website responsive.
You can see on this gif that the breakpoint is making the column smaller, but not changing the dimensions of the image itself: https://imgur.com/7tvzdtB

Comment: Okay Fox, now what do you suggets me? Is there any universal solution to this problem?

Comment: I updated my original answer with a quick solution. If you want a *really* quick solution, it also works if you just set the image size to "219px" instead of "250px".

Comment: Updated the answer with the second option as well.

Comment: Thanks Fox, I accepted your answer as it works. But I just need little explanation of how did u calculate the 210px? Will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Add width and height property in image tag.

```
<header class="sidebar-section">
            <div class="header-logo">
                <a class="logo" href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" width="250"></a>
            </div>
            <a class="elemadded responsive-link" href="#">Menu</a>
            <div class="navbar-vertical">
                <ul class="main-menu">


                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
```